# Sorting posts to make those with post thumbnail show up first

Tags: loop, sort

I am trying to sort post with If have post thumbnail list posts show first(i need the posts without thumbnail to show after it) by title.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id title'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Note : It have to be only one loop.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to sort all the posts alphabetically but show those with a featured_image first, then the rest, all in one loop?

Comment: Yes exactly. The posts with thumbnail first then the ones without it.

Comment: How about setting menu_order to 1 for posts with a thumbnail and then using the orderby option? Using a hook you should be able to set menu_order automatically when a post has a thumbnail.

Comment: If you are going to do this in query, you have to get all posts regardless and then sort them using `usort()`

Comment: @z80crew I was thinking about some thing like that but there are a lot of posts that already exists. I think that i may have to make a bulk menu_order setting to all previous posts just for one time and then add save_post action to deal with new posts. Not the optimal solution but it works.

Comment: You could use `pre_get_posts` to get all the posts with a featured image and then on your query list all the posts without one.